# Firebase [String:Any] but I need it to be an Dictionary

Tags: database, swift, firebase

I was using Dictionary now we have to use `[String:Any]`

```
func getCompanyNameFromFireBase(uid:String, passWord: String) {

    if CompanyData.companyName == "" {

        WhoAreYouRefKey.observe(.value){ (snap7: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        let  CompanyLoaderFromFireBaseDictionary:[String : Any] = ((snap7.value!) as! NSDictionary) as! [String : Any]

        for this in CompanyLoaderFromFireBaseDictionary.allKeys {
            WhoAreYouRefKey.child("\(this as! String)").observe(.Value){ (snap2: FIRDataSnapshot) in

            let array = (snap2.value) as! Dictionary
```

It fails because it is not seeing the keys or values.

Comment: Elaborate your error , line of error and your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getCompanyNameFromFireBase(uid:String, passWord: String) {

  if CompanyData.companyName == "" {

    WhoAreYouRefKey.observe(.value){ (snap7: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    let  temp[String : Any] = ((snap7.value!)  as! [String : Any]

let CompanyLoaderFromFireBaseDictionary = temp as! NSDictionary

    for this in CompanyLoaderFromFireBaseDictionary.allKeys {
        WhoAreYouRefKey.child("\(this as! String)").observe(.Value){ (snap2: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        let array = (snap2.value) as! Dictionary
```

Comment: You should edit your original response rather than add this code as an answer